# show images that are uploaded by user in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I have a page which allows a user to upload an image and that image is stored by the models.py file in the {{MEDIA_ROOT}}/image/image1.jpg
i want to display this image through a html image tag on another web page

My html code snippet is `<img  border="2" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/{{ghar.image}}" alt="venture picture here"/>`

here ghar is the object that has the details abt the image

Can anyone help me to do the same

i am using Django as the framework and sqlite3 as the DB

**Update**:

This is my models.py function

```
from django.db import models

class GharData(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    typeOfProperty = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    typeOfPlace = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    ownerName = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ownerEmail = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nameOfVenture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    designedBy = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    ownerPhone = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ownerName


class ImageData(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(GharData, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/',blank=True,null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='video/',blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.property.ownerName
```

This is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'gharnivas.views.index'),
        url(r'^search/$', 'gharnivas.views.search'),
    url(r'^venture/(?P<ghar_id>\d+)/$', 'gharnivas.views.venture'),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crate a separate object which has the access to ImageData class with the id of GharData class.

```
def Show_something(request, ghar_id):
    g = get_object_or_404(GharData, pk=ghar_id)
    i = g.images.all()
    return render_to_response('YOUR_APP/iventure.html', {'ghar': g, 'imagedata' :i }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

<img  border="2" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ imagedata.image }}" alt="venture picture here"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="{{ [MODEL_OBJECT].[IMAGE_FIELD].url }}" />`

In your case:

`<img border="2" src="{{ghar.image.url}}" alt="venture picture here" />`

Comment: Do you use `upload_to` in your model? Or handle uploading somehow manually? If second – `src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ghar.image.name}}"` (or `src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/{{ghar.image.name}}"`)

Comment: @DrTyrsa : I have updated the question.. Could you checking it please let me know about my mistake ?

Comment: As I see, `ghar` object has no attribute `image`, right? So you can't show it. And a `ghar` can have several images and you should decide which to show. If you want the first, than `src="{{ ghar.images.0.image.url }}"` will work, but it's better to make this code property of `GharData` model.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: I did try it, but again no results. The thing is the Image is stored in a folder `/project/templates/media/image/`. The normal image of the background gets loaded as i have the rendered the backgroung image in view.py. Now it is not showing the object `ghar`(s) image. Regarding the property to be created for GharData, should i just create a new filed? What should that filed be?

Comment: What does `ghar.images.0.image.url` output? Do you have any objects in `ghar.images` queryset? I think you need to create a property `image` for your model `GharData` and return desired image for `self.images` queryset.